# Git repo sync error: branch XYZ is published (but not merged) and is now 1 commits behind

Tags: git, repository

I had submitted two patchsets for a change, the first with "git commit -s", and the
subsequent with git commit --amend -s". After the review of second patchset, was asked to
make some more modifications for an improvement. The overall  change/patch itself is
pending approval, and has not yet been merged.

I made the modificatione needed, and did “git add” on 6 (6 files had changed since the
last patchset) of the total 7 files that are part of the change, and did a "git commit --
amend -s". I did a "repo sync", no errors, but did not "repo upload" yet.

Then I remembered that one of the files had been set incorrectly with non-default values 
for two debug flags in the above commit. So I went back and changed that one file again,
then did an “git add” of that one file, and a “git commit --amend -s”, which went through
withour errors, just like the earlier “git add” and “git commit --amend -s” above.

When I did a repo sync again prior to doing the repo upload, I got the following error:

"error: : branch topic1 is published (but not merged) and is now 1
commits behind"

What is the best/easiest way to fix this and do the repo upload?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I was just searching for this and happened upon the answer.  do "git rebase ".  This will reparent your changes to the updated branch.  You might need to perform merges as prompted.

Answer (score 3):

Use "repo rebase"

---

### Summary

Rebase local branches on upstream branch

Usage: repo rebase {[...] | -i ...}

Options:
  -h, --help          show this help message and exit
  -i, --interactive   interactive rebase (single project only)
  -f, --force-rebase  Pass --force-rebase to git rebase
  --no-ff             Pass --no-ff to git rebase
  -q, --quiet         Pass --quiet to git rebase
  --autosquash        Pass --autosquash to git rebase
  --whitespace=WS     Pass --whitespace to git rebase
  --auto-stash        Stash local modifications before starting

### Description

'repo rebase' uses git rebase to move local changes in the current topic
branch to the HEAD of the upstream history, useful when you have made
commits in a topic branch but need to incorporate new upstream changes
"underneath" them.